# Single parameters to new() must be a HASH ref data

Tags: perl

I have a perl script and it works on perl version 5.8.8 but 5.14 got that error: Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at

Here is my code:

```
$session->begin_privileged({ $_enable_password })
```

Previously it was like this:

```
$session->begin_privileged( $_enable_password )
```

And at this time I get this error:

```
Single parameters to new() must be a HASH ref data
```

I have similar typed lines like above and I get same Single parameters error on each.

I googled it but could not find a regular solution.

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: Well, it clearly says it wants a hash ref. What is it you think that anyone here is going to tell you that's different from that? It also tells you that the hash ref you sent has an odd number of elements, which is to say one element `$_enable_password`. Presumably you would do something like `{ enable_password => $_enable_password }`.

Comment: Every hash, referenced or not, mush have pairs of key and value.

Comment: What class is the object `$session`? You should look at the documentation for the module to see how to pass parameters. We cannot tell what the hash is supposed to look like. Are you sure `$_enable_password` hasn't changed? It looks very much like it used to be a hash reference and now it is not.

Comment: It looks very much like this might be [`Net::Appliance::Session`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::Appliance::Session)?

Comment: It uses Net::Appliance::Session library the thing is it works with perl 5.8.8. After upgrading to 5.14 it stopped working.

Comment: I would have been nice if you had told us the module you were using in the first place. Luckily I guessed correctly. See my answer. But it is *highly* unlikely that this difference is due to a change to Perl version 14.

Comment: It is a much more likely explanation that `$_enable_password` should be a hash reference and isn't being set up correctly, than that Perl v14 has stopped it working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `$session` is an instance of [`Net::Appliance::Session`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aAppliance%3a%3aSession) then your call should look like this:

```
$session->begin_privileged({ password => $_enable_password });
```

But I am still not sure that `$_enable_password` isn't a hash reference in the first place, in which case you should pass it as a single parameter without enclosing braces. It is a much more likely explanation that `$_enable_password` isn't being set up correctly than that Perl v14 has stopped it working.

Comment: Old versions of N::A::S accepted a single password parameter, and he upgraded the module when he upgraded his Perl. The module (not Perl) broke backwards compatibility.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. That explains a lot, and should be a comment on the question.

Comment: I figured you'd want to update the "It is a much more likely explanation" part of the answer.